# I need to check that application has been closed or in background in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to know if we press home or back button in android... can we close the application activity?
If not than how can we know that the app activity is running or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close application when You press the home or back button.

try this code

```
  @Override

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK==keyCode || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME==keycode)
    {   

        finish();
    }       
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: hello Kannappan... i tried your code but the activity doesnt finishes if i open the app again it is still at the same spot...

Comment: i added @Override... infact i also added a toast just above finish()... it shows me the toast so that means it comes inside the function still it is not making the application to close....

Comment: @Override does nothing in this context because it will be removed from the compiler and is only to ensure (during development) you really override an existing method.

Comment: try this finishActivity(int requestCode)

Comment: or use this Activity.this.finish()

Comment: @kannappan i used Activity.this.finish also and its not working... ALthough i havent used finishActivity(int requestCode) as i dont know how to obtain requestCode....

Comment: Requestcode is nothing but it't just integer..u can give any integer no.